# How to access again a jquery function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have a dynamic table that can search, display search in pagination, and autocompute fields.
The scenario is

1. The user will search his/her items in the search box
2. The system will display the search result in a pagination if the result is too many to display
3. After that, the user can choose from the search result
4. After choosing, the system will generate a table with the list of selected items
5. From the table there are some text fields and selectbox. Actually it is also a dynamic form.
6. The textfields are auto-computed by the jasvascript.

My problem is:

1. When the user search another item the pagination won't work properly. It display my data but doesn't paginate
2. The auto-compute won't work after choosing an item/s.

I am using Codeigniter as my framework. The search is ajax process.
Here's my code:

```
    var counter_code = 1;
    var counter_item = 1;
    var counter_qty = 1;
    var counter_unit = 1;
    var counter_price = 1;
    var counter_total = 1;

   //automatic computation in rows
    $('[id^=qty],[id^=price]').on('change',function() {

        var index = this.id.match(/\d+/)[0];
        var qty = parseInt($('#qty'+index).val());
        var price = parseFloat($('#price'+index).val());
        var disc = $("#discount").val();
        var lessitem = $("#purchase_return").val();
        var total = 0;


        $('#total'+index).val((qty * price ? qty * price : 0).toFixed(2));

        var total = 0;
        $('[id^=total]').each(function(index){
            total+=parseFloat($(this).val()?$(this).val():0);
        });

        var totalAll = $('#sum_of_total').val(total.toFixed(2));

        var vatable = 0;
        var vatable_amt = 0;
        var totalVat = 0;
        var computeDisc = 0;
        var computeLess =0;

        if($("#tin_number").val().length != 0){
            vatable = total / 1.12;
            vatable_amt = vatable * 0.12;
            totalVat = vatable + vatable_amt;

        }else{
            totalVat = total;


        }

        $('#vatable').val(vatable.toFixed(2)); 
        $("#vatable_amount").val(vatable_amt.toFixed(2));
        var gtotal = $("#gtotal").val(totalVat.toFixed(2));
        $("#total_amt_due").val(gtotal.toFixed(2));

    });

    $("#discount").on('change',function(){
        var totalSales = $("#gtotal").val();
        var discountedAmt = $("#discount").val();
        var returnAmt = $("#purchase_return").val();
        var computeTotalDisc = (totalSales - discountedAmt) - returnAmt;
        $("#total_amt_due").val(computeTotalDisc.toFixed(2));
    });

    $("#purchase_return").on('change',function(){
        var totalSalesx = ($("#gtotal").val() - $("#purchase_return").val() - $("#discount").val());
        $("#total_amt_due").val(totalSalesx.toFixed(2));
    });

 $('#search-btn').on('click',function(){

        var query = $("#keyword").val();
        //var query_url = "<?php echo site_url('item_model/searchItem/" + query + "'); ?>";
        var query_url = "<?php echo site_url('item_controller/searchItem'); ?>";

        $.ajax({

            type:'POST',
            url: query_url,
            data:{query: $("#keyword").val()},
            dataType:'json',
            async: false,
            success:function(d){

                //$('.display').dataTable().fnDestroy( true );

                $("#example tbody").html("");

                for(i in d){

                    $("#example tbody").append("<tr><td style='text-align: center; color:' data-code='TRUE'>" + d[i]['code'] + "</td><td style='text-align: left' data-name='TRUE'>" + d[i]['name'] + "</td><td><div style='text-align: center'><input type='button' value='ADD' class='k-button' id='" + d[i]['code'] + "' data-item=TRUE /></div></td></tr>");

                }

                //$("#search_result").show('blind');

                $("[data-item]").on('click',function(){

                    var code = $(this).parents('tr').find('[data-code]').html();
                    var name = $(this).parents('tr').find('[data-name]').html();
                    //console.log(code,name);
                    $("#grid1 tbody").append("<tr><td style='text-align: center; width: 20%'><input type='text' value=" + code + " readonly style='width:50px; background-color: transparent; border-style: none' id=code" + counter_code++ +" /></td><td style='text-align: center; width: 40%'><input type='text' style='width: 90%; background-color: transparent; border-style: none' value='" + name + "' id=item"+ counter_item++ +" readonly /></td><td style='text-align: center'><input type='text' name='qty[]' id=qty"+ counter_qty++ +" style='text-align: center; width: 50px;' /></td><td style='text-align: center'><div align='center'><select style='width:100px; display: block' name='unit[]' id=unit"+ counter_unit++ +" ><option value=''>----</option><option value='pc/pcs'>PC/PCS</option><option value='BOX/BOXES'>BOX/BOXES</option></select></div></td><td style='text-align: center'><input type='text' name='price[]' id=price"+ counter_price++ +" style='text-align: right; width: 100px;' onblur='' /></td><td style='text-align: center'><input type='text' name='total[]' id=total"+ counter_total++ +" style='font-family: courier; text-align: right; background-color: lightgray; color: red; width: 100px;' readonly='readonly' value='' /></td></tr>");

                });

                $('.display').dataTable({
                    "bPaginate": true,
                    "bLengthChange": true,
                    "bFilter": true,
                    "bSort": true,
                    "bInfo": true,
                    "bAutoWidth": false,
                    "bDestroy": true,
                    "bJQueryUI": false,
                    "bRetrieve": true,
                    "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
                    "iDisplayLength": 25,
                    "destroy": true
                });

            },

        });    

    });
```

---

```
<div id="search_result" class="k-content">
     <div class="k-header" id="item-view-list" align="center">

        <table border="0" style="width: 80%; align: left" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="10" align="left">
            <tr>
                <td colspan="3">
                    <h5>SEARCH ITEM</h5>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="width: 3%">
                    <label>Name/Description</label>
                </td>
                <td style="width: 40%">
                    <input type="text" name="keyword" id="keyword" style="width: 80%" /> <input type="button" value="SEARCH" id="search-btn" class="k-button" style="font-size: 12px" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>

        <hr />

        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="display" id="example" style="font-size:small; width: 100%">
            <thead>
                <tr>

                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>CODE</th>
                    <th>NAME/DESCRIPTION</th>
                    <th></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>

            </tbody>
        </table>
        <br />

    </div>
</div>

<div class="k-content">
    <div class="k-header" id="item-view-list" align="center">

         <table id="grid1" border="0" style="width: 100%" cellpadding="10">

                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th style="text-align: center;">CODE</th>
                        <th style="text-align: center;">DESCRIPTION</th>
                        <th style="text-align: center;">QTY</th>
                        <th style="text-align: center;">UNIT</th>
                        <th style="text-align: center;">UNIT PRICE</th>
                        <th style="text-align: center;">TOTAL AMOUNT</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>

                <tbody>

                </tbody>
            </table>

            <hr />

            <div align="right">

                <table border="0" cellpadding="10">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <label>Shipping fee?</label>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="checkbox" id="yes_shipping" onclick="document.getElementById('shipping_fee').style.display = (this.checked) ? '' : 'none';" />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" placeholder="Amount (0.00)" id="shipping_fee" style="display: none" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>

            </div>

            <hr />
            <div align="right">

                <table>
                        <tr>
                            <td></td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td>VATable Amount:</td>
                            <td><input type="text" class="k-textbox" value="" readonly="readonly" style="color: red; text-align: right; font-family: courier; background-color: lightgray;" name="vatable" id="vatable" /></td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                            <td></td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td>VAT Input:</td>
                            <td><input type="text" class="k-textbox" value="" readonly="readonly" style="color: red; text-align: right; font-family: courier; background-color: lightgray;" name="vatable_amount" id="vatable_amount" /></td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                            <td></td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td>TOTAL SALES:</td>
                            <td><input type="text" class="k-textbox" value="" readonly="readonly" style="color: red; text-align: right; font-family: courier; background-color: lightgray;" name="subtotal" id="gtotal" /></td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                            <td></td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td>PURCHASE DISCOUNT:</td>
                            <td><input type="text" class="k-textbox" value="" style="color: red; text-align: right; font-family: courier" name="discount" id="discount" placeholder="Enter discount" maxlength="2" required="required"/></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td></td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td>PURCHASE RETURN:</td>
                            <td><input type="text" class="k-textbox" value="" style="color: red; text-align: right; font-family: courier" name="purchase_return" id="purchase_return"/></td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                            <td></td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td>TOTAL AMOUNT DUE:</td>
                            <td><input type="text" class="k-textbox" value="0.00" style="color: red; text-align: right; font-family: courier; background-color: lightgray;" name="total_amt_due" id="total_amt_due" readonly="readonly" /></td>
                        </tr>
                        <input type="hidden" id="sum_of_total" name="sum_of_total" />
                </table>
```

Comment: I really dont understand the question. Can you put it on one line / sentence, eg I want to...? When pagination not work, you have done something wring. What is "auto-compute"? Can you setup af fiddle? - you can use this starting point http://jsfiddle.net/5dPTD/

Answer (score 0):

Move the `$('.display').dataTable(...` function call to somewhere outside of your ajax call's success function. It's getting called every time the user submits a keyword. I haven't used dataTable so this is just my first hunch. 2nd problem may be that you're binding a click event handler to `$("[data-item]")` here too. When the user submits a 2nd keyword this event handler will get duplicated on top of the first one and the will both fire on the next click. Try unbinding it first: `$("[data-item]").unbind("click")`, then call `on` as you were.